# Replace words inside input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code changes words to numbers,
but when I paste text like: three four one one four five six one
receive:
3411456one

If I click the text input again, the one change to 1
but I want it to work smooth when paste on the first time.

```js
$('#word').on('change keyup paste',function(){
var a=document.getElementById('word').value; 
var b=a
.replace('zero','0')
.replace('one','1')
.replace('two','2')
.replace('three','3')
.replace('four','4')
.replace('five','5')
.replace('six','6')
.replace('seven','7')
.replace('eight','8')
.replace('nine','9')
.replace('','')
document.getElementById('word').value=b;});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="word" type="text">
```

Comment: Please post code here instead of just fiddles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`replace` with string avoid last occurrence. So you should use Regular Expression with Global matching (`g` flag).

```js
$('#word').on('change keyup paste input',function(){
var a=document.getElementById('word').value; 
var b=a
.replace(/zero/g,'0')
.replace(/one/g,'1')
.replace(/two/g,'2')
.replace(/three/g,'3')
.replace(/four/g,'4')
.replace(/five/g,'5')
.replace(/six/g,'6')
.replace(/seven/g,'7')
.replace(/eight/g,'8')
.replace(/nine/g,'9')
.replace('','');
document.getElementById('word').value=b;});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div style="position:absolute;top:10px;left:12px;width:310px">
<br>
<br>
<input id="word" type="text">
<table id="get" style="line-height:0px" alt=""><tbody></tbody></table>
</div>
<div style="position:absolute;top:10px;right:200px;text-align:center">
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src=''></script>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should replace the global occurrences. `replace` function replaces the first occurrence and when you add `/g` that replace all the occurances.

```
$('#word').on('change keyup paste',function(){
var a=document.getElementById('word').value; 
var b=a
.replace(/zero/g,'0')
.replace(/one/g,'1')
.replace(/two/g,'2')
.replace(/three/g,'3')
.replace(/four/g,'4')
.replace(/five/g,'5')
.replace(/six/g,'6')
.replace(/seven/g,'7')
.replace(/eight/g,'8')
.replace(/nine/g,'9')
.replace('','')
document.getElementById('word').value=b;});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshatta/2155p84q/2/)